# Insert unicode text in MySql4 throught ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, mysql, unicode, utf-8

I'm writing a new website for an institute which has 4000 users that are stored in MySql4 !

I'm using mysql-connector/net to connect to MySql database throught asp.net,

Everything is OK, EXCEPT updating the info which are in unicode mode !

Unfortunately I don't know lot about unicode !

Connecting and reading data from MySql database is like this :

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
...
MySqlConnection con;
MySqlCommand cmd;

string tempstr = "Database=DB-NAME;Data Source=SOURCE;charset=utf8;User Id=USER;Password=PASS";
con = new MySqlConnection(tempstr);
con.Open();
cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "select * from list_membership";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();
```

Now when I read an address for example I get sth like this: **Ø²ÙØ¬Ø§Ù**

Fortunately I've solved it using the function blew:

```
public string DecodeFromUtf8(string utf8String)
{
   // copy the string as UTF-8 bytes.
   byte[] utf8Bytes = new byte[utf8String.Length];
   for (int i = 0; i < utf8String.Length; ++i)
   {
       //Debug.Assert( 0 <= utf8String[i] && utf8String[i] <= 255, "the char must be in byte's range");
       utf8Bytes[i] = (byte)utf8String[i];
   }
   return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes, 0, utf8Bytes.Length);
}
```

Now I send the junky string to the function and I get correct form like this : زنجان  (persian language)

The problem is that when I want to update or insert address field for instance, nothing will store in the database except some question marks like this: **???? ?????**

Anyone know what should I do ?!
Is there any reverse form for DecodeFromUtf8 function ?

Excuse my bad english,
Thanks.

Comment: MySQL 4 has practically no support for character encodings, can't you upgrade?

Comment: Oops ! But the previous website was written in PHP, and it stores and reads these strings without any decoding or anything else ! I think PHP and MySql 4 is compatible with these unicode strings, But ASP.NET is not ! (or mysql/connector/net is not !)

Comment: PHP is as ignorant of character encodings and Unicode as MySQL 4; in both strings are arbitrary sequences of bytes, and bringing in a component that is Unicode aware like .Net or Java is problematic.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps with the problem, but the reverse of `DecodeFromUtf8` should look something like this:

```
public string EncodeToMySQL4(string str)
{
   Encoding latin1 = new Encoding(1252);
   return latin1.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Joni. It's 90% complete :) now I can store to MySql database, But the only problem is that when I read from database and use DecodeFromUtf8(), I get a square instead of some characters ! although it's all better than question marks, do you know any other encoding ways?

Comment: See if this fixes it: `byte[] utf8Bytes = new Encoding(1252).GetBytes(utf8String);`

Comment: No. It didn't help. I figured that those characters which I get square instead of them, store as a question mark in my database, such as : Ø²Ù?Ø¬Ø§Ù?

Comment: If they are stored with a question mark the data is broken: instead of a question mark (byte `3F`) you should have a "dagger" † (byte `86`). Use the `HEX` function in MySQL to check which bytes are stored.