# Can't correctly read emoji from Mysql using ODBC

Tags: mysql, utf-8, vbscript, asp-classic, odbc

I've read many threads on Stack and other forums, but still can't figure how to make it work.

**The configuration**

- I have a *MySQL 8.0* database named *test*, and configured it with default *CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_as_ci*.
- Inside there's a table creatively named *table*, this too configured as *utf8mb4* and *utf8mb4_0900_as_ci*.
- The only field is named *field* and is a blob type, where I write and read encoded data using *AES_ENCRYPT/DECRYPT*
- *VBScript classic* connect to it using the last *ODBC 8 UNICODE* driver
- I've tried the *SET NAMES* statement but is not supported in this ODBC version. Instead the *charset* is included directly in the connection string.

**Following other threads, I made a test file**

- without any external include
- saved as UTF8
- specified all the possible Vbscript *Codepage* and *Charset* at the beginning of the file
- the connection string specifies a charset, I've tried both *ucs2* and *utf8mb4*
- the html segment specifies the utf charset both in the Content Type and in the form
- when reading from the database I specify to *CONVERT USING utf8mb4*

The page is setup to be the simplest test possible, with a form on top, and the results listed below.

All the simple text is processed correctly, while any ***emoji*** is read as ***?***

```
For example, if this is the text passed through the form -> hello       
this is what is returned -> hello ? ? ? ? ? ? ?
```

Executing the same SELECT query in *Workbench 8*, shows the correct text with the emoji, so it's not a problem directly related to the Codepage or Charset, or when it writes the data, but only when it read them.
VarType report the *RS("Field")* as a simple string / 8.
I've spent the last days studying and testing all the possible solutions, but can't solve it :/

```
<%@Language="VBScript" CodePage="65001"%>
<% Option Explicit %>
<%
' THE PAGE ENCODING
Response.ContentType = "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
Session.CodePage = 65001
Response.CodePage = 65001
Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"

'----------------------------------------------------------------

dim dbConn, sql, RS

' SIMPLE CONNECTION STRING
' NOTE THAT I'VE TRIED BOTH charset=ucs2 AND charset=utf8mb4
Set dbConn = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Connection")
dbConn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 UNICODE Driver}; SERVER=127.0.0.1; PORT=3306; DATABASE=test; Uid=user; Pwd=password; charset=ucs2;"

'----------------------------------------------------------------

%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>test MySQL UTF-8</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action="?action=insert" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <textarea name="text"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Insert">
  </form>
<%

'----------------------------------------------------------------

' INSERT THE STRING WHEN THE FORM IS SUBMITTED
If Request.Querystring("action") = "insert" Then

    sql = "INSERT INTO table (Field) VALUES(AES_ENCRYPT('" & Request.Form("text") & "', 'AES_Key'))"
    Response.Write(sql & "</br>")
    dbConn.execute(sql)

End If

'----------------------------------------------------------------

' LIST ALL THE RECORDS FROM THE TABLE
sql = "SELECT CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT(Field, 'AES_Key') USING utf8mb4) AS Field FROM table"
Set RS = dbconn.execute(sql)

Do Until RS.EOF

    Response.Write(RS("Field") & "</br>")
    RS.MoveNext

Loop
RS.close

dbConn.close

%>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows ODBC driver - retrieved emoji data rendered as?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59010774/windows-odbc-driver-retrieved-emoji-data-rendered-as)

Comment: @user692942 The same operator of that question opened another one almost identical https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58943772/emoji-data-retrieved-via-odbc-connection-appears-as-question-mark?noredirect=1#comment118185114_58943772 In the comment I asked him if in the end has been able to solve it, and the response is "I ported the code to PHP" XD Saddly for me it's not an option.

Comment: I have found that in some cases emojiis can be illegal characters.